# How do work around Kmeans value error?

Tags: clustering, k-means, social-network-analysis, twitter, context-vector

I am working on a social network analysis project. My data comes from twitter. Before I run the analysis, I intend to apply clustering- specifically Kmeans to determine how to seperate tweets in categories.

**I vectorized my data using the following code:**

```
vectorizer3 = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = stop_words, tokenizer = tokenize, max_features = 1000)


X3=vectorizer3.fit_transform(df_connections['text'].values.astype('str'))

word_features3 = vectorizer3.get_feature_names_out()

len(word_features3)
```

**Next, I run the following code:**

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


clusters = [2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15]

for i in clusters :
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, n_init = 5, random_state = 42)
    kmeans.fit(i)
    print("Number of clusters:", i)
    common_words = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:,-1:-11:-1]
    for num, centroid in enumerate(common_words):
        print(str(num) + ' : ' + ', '.join(word_features3[word] for word in centroid))
    new_col_name = str(i) + "_clusters"
    tweets[new_col_name] = kmeans.labels_
```

**I receive the following error message:**

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=2.0.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Thank you.

Comment: the error seems to be here: ``kmeans.fit(i)``you are passing an integer when you should pass a array/data frame like so: ``kmeans.fit(X3)``

Comment: @Multivac Thank you. X3 seems to fix it and I am able to get the needed clusters. But I am getting an IndexError: Index dimension must be <=2


File ~IndexMixin._asindices(self, idx, length)
    159     raise IndexError('invalid index') from e
    161 if x.ndim not in (1, 2):
--> 162     raise IndexError('Index dimension must be <= 2')
    164 if x.size == 0:
    165     return x

IndexError: Index dimension must be <= 2

Comment: Fixed!

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


clusters = [5]

for i in clusters :
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, n_init = 5, random_state = 42)
    kmeans.fit(X3)
    print("Number of clusters:", i)
    common_words = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:,-1:-11:-1]
    for num, centroid in enumerate(common_words):
        print(str(num) + ' : ' + ', '.join(word_features3[word] for word in centroid))
    new_col_name = str(i) + "_clusters"
    tweets[new_col_name] = kmeans.labels_